# Am I on the right track? Rock Paper Scissors (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, if-statement, return

I am a completely beginner in JavaScript and currently working on the [Rock Paper Scissors project](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/foundations-rock-paper-scissors) from The Odin Project:

> 3. Your game is going to play against the computer, so begin with a function called `computerPlay` that will randomly return either ‘Rock’, ‘Paper’ or ‘Scissors’. We’ll use this function in the game to make the computer’s play. *Tip: use the console to make sure this is returning the expected output before moving to the next step!*
> 4. Write a function that plays a single round of Rock Paper Scissors. The function should take two parameters - the `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` - and then return a string that declares the winner of the round like so: `"You Lose! Paper beats Rock"`
>
>    a. Make your function’s playerSelection parameter case-insensitive (so users can input `rock`, `ROCK`, `RocK` or any other variation).
> 5. **Important note:** you want to `return` the results of this function call, **not** `console.log()` them. [...]
> 6. Write a NEW function called `game()`. Call the `playRound` function *inside* of this one to play a 5 round game that keeps score and reports a winner or loser at the end.
>
>    a. Remember loops? This is a great opportunity to use one to play those five rounds
>
>    b. At this point you should be using `console.log()` to display the results of each round and the winner at the end.
>
>    c. Use `prompt()` to get input from the user. Read the docs here if you need to.
>
>    d. Feel free to re-work your previous functions if you need to. Specifically, you might want to change the return value to something more useful.
>
>    e. Feel free to create more “helper” functions if you think it would be useful.

I am trying my best to not look on how others solved it but I've been doing this for almost 2 days now and I just want to know if am I even on the right track? or should I completely change how I have done this?

```
function computerPlay() {
   const pick = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
   return pick[Math.floor(Math.random() * pick.length)];
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
   if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
      return `It's a tie! you both picked ${playerSelection}`;
   } else if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors") {
      return "You win! Rock beats Scissors";
   } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock") {
      return "You win! Paper beats Rock";
   } else if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper") {
      return "You win! Scissors beats Paper";
   } else {
      return `You lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
   }
}

const playerSelection = prompt("Start the game by picking among 'Rock, Paper, Scissors'").toLowerCase();
const computerSelection = computerPlay();
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection))
```

Comment: It looks good! Maybe as @Aleti suggests make it a switch case for readability and add a command to play again without having to refresh. But it looks good for your first try!

Comment: @Obsidianlab thank you for the nice words. I was kinda demotivated and I needed to hear that. I'll take note of using switch case, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

You created the functions `computerPlay` and `playRound` according to the requirements given in the challenge.

Now you have that working, you should continue with the next step: create the `game` function. You already did the `prompt` part.

When you get to the part where you need to maintain the score, you'll find that it will be better for `playRound` to return a value, like -1, 0, 1 depending on the outcome, as that is easier to work with to update the score. And that value can then also be used to output a message.

Comment: Thank you so muccchhh!!! I am now motivated to move on to the next part. This is such a big help, appreciate it so much

Answer (score -2):

Hy shi shi.

For each condition you return a result. It means that you do not need to use else if and just go with if statements. Personally i hate else if conditions
Maybe a switch is better for readability.

Comment: No that is the final case. In that case you loose. The other three are the only cases you win with. It is correct like this.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I didnt read until the last else :))

Comment: thank youuu i'll take note of using switch case